# date time Php validation against the variable

Tags: php

hi all ive been up all night trying to get this work, im trying to test the `$year` value against the date to make sure that it is not less than the current date

here is my code at the moment it doesn't seem to work im not sure what im doing wrong

```
   public function checkDateField($month, $day, $year)
   {
        if (!is_numeric($month) || !is_numeric($day) || !is_numeric($year) || !checkdate($month, $day, $year)< date("m-d-y")) {
            $msg = '*Invalid date';


        }
        return $msg;    
   }
```

Comment: `is_numeric` checks here are redundant

Answer (score 1):

Just do a straight comparison:

```
if (checkdate($month, $day, $year) && mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year) > mktime(0, 0, 1)) {
    echo 'Valid date';
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid date';
}
```

This will check that the supplied variables when assembled makes a valid Gregorian date, and if so that the date is greater than 00:00:01 of the current day.

Answer (score 1):

if(strtotime(("1 January ".$year)) < strtotime("now") )
 echo 'Invalid Date';

hope that helps